# Chaining two API calls in Angular NGRX Effect

Tags: angular, typescript, ngrx, ngrx-effects

I am trying to resolve a small issue but getting no where with it. I have an effect which gets called with payload. I need to call an API for result and then pass that result and the payload in to another API. What i have tried so far is as follow which is not working as it says the action should return a type.

```
  @Effect()
  fetchSomething$ = this.actions
    .ofType(fromProfileAction.FETCH_POST)
    .map(action => action)
    .switchMap(payload => Observable.forkJoin([
      Observable.of(payload),
      this.xyzService.getXyz()
    ]))
    .switchMap(data => {
      const [action, xyz] = data;
      return this.postsService
          .abc(action.payload)
          .pipe(
            map(async (response: any) => {
              if (response.res) {
                const result = res.name + " - " + Xyz;
                action.payload.result = result;
              }
              return new fromProfileAction.FetchPostSuccess(action.payload);
            }),
            catchError(err => of(new fromProfileAction.FetchPostFailure({ err })))
          );
    });
```

Any pointer in right direction.

Comment: new fromProfileAction.FetchPostSuccess(action);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
fetchSomething$ = this.actions
    .ofType(fromProfileAction.FETCH_POST)
    .map(action => action.payload)
    .switchMap(payload => this.xyzService.getXyz(payload)))
    .switchMap(data => {      
      return this.postsService
          .abc(data)
          .pipe(
            map(async (response: any) => {
              if (response.res) {
                const result = res.name + " - " + Xyz;
                action.payload.result = result;
              }
              return new fromProfileAction.FetchPostSuccess(action.payload);
            }),
            catchError(err => of(new fromProfileAction.FetchPostFailure({ err })))
          );
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

```
@Effect() fetchSomething$ = this.actions .ofType(fromProfileAction.FETCH_POST) .map(action => action) .switchMap(payload => return  Observable.forkJoin([ Observable.of(payload), this.xyzService.getXyz() ])) .switchMap(data => { const [action, xyz] = data; return this.postsService .abc(action.payload) .pipe( map(async (response: any) => { if (response.res) { const result = res.name + " - " + Xyz; action.payload.result = result; } return new fromProfileAction.FetchPostSuccess(action.payload); }), catchError(err => of(new fromProfileAction.FetchPostFailure({ err }))) ); });
```

Try the abpve code. You have to return the result in first switch map.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do

```
@Injectable()
export class SomeEffects {

  someAction$ = createEffect(() =>
    this.actions$.pipe(
      ofType(someEvent),
      exhaustMap((action) =>
        this.service1.get(action.someID).pipe(
          map((someObject) => someObjectLoaded({ someObject})),
        )
      )
    )
  );

  someObjectLoaded$ = createEffect(() =>
    this.actions$.pipe(
      ofType(someObjectLoaded),
      exhaustMap((action) => this.service2.get(action.someObject.someOtherID)
        .pipe(map((someOtherObject) => someOtherObjectLoaded({ someOtherObject} )))
      )
    )
  );

  constructor(
    private actions$: Actions,
    private service1: Service1,
    private service2: Service2
  ) {
  }
}
```